# Could not run flutter project in VScode due to issue in gradle build

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

When I start my app on my emulator I get this message:

```
Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip'.
Could not open cp_init remapped class cache for 6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66 (C:\Users\wajda\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\eclipsePlugin_c0l4vaujpv5bvvumb2lpg6av6\6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66\cp_init40e7ec637808a9c747559d26950b1d9b).
Could not open cp_init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\wajda\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\ee5be1c89f554029b67599ff9c63b205\redhat.java\jdt_ws\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.buildship.core\init.d\eclipsePlugin.gradle' (C:\Users\wajda\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts\6a5krabdzij62jglcll542e66\cp_init\cp_init40e7ec637808a9c747559d26950b1d9b).
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.Verifier
```

I was wondering how I can fix this issue?
Should I just reinstall vs code and android studio?

Comment: your build wants `gradle-5.6.2` - what version of `gardle` do you have?

Comment: @pskink I just checked and its 5.6.2 in the wrapper

Comment: @pskink I do not, I downloaded Android Studios and VS Code so it probably came with one of those so thats why its in a wrapper ( I think)

Comment: so check `C:\Users\wajda\.gradle\caches`

Comment: @pskink its 5.6.2

Comment: does it have any content? for example my `gradle-5.6.2-all` folder has 437 MB: `437M    <$HOME>/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-5.6.2-all/`

Comment: @pskink yes that directory you gave me exists and mine is 377 MB

Comment: 100 MB difference? maybe it broken? tried to remove it completely and let vscode or as reinstall it again?

Comment: @pskink will it automatically reinstall it or will I have to force it somehow? and do I delete /.gradle completely or just 5.6.2?

Comment: all you need is working internet connection

Comment: @pskink sorry I edited my comment, do I delete /.gradle or just 5.6.2?

Comment: just 5.6.2 folder

Comment: @pskink it wont let me delete because it says something is using 5.6.2 but nothing is open.

Comment: there must be some `gradle` daemon process running, check it

Comment: @pskink again sorry for asking so many questions but where do I find this because I tried checking task manager but I cant any daemon process running